# Can DeviceId (UDID) in android can be change in case of os upadate?

Tags: android, udid

following code i have use  to get udid in android . Any chances that below method should not return unique value?

```
  TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String deviceId;
    if (telephonyManager.getDeviceId() != null)
        deviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId(); //*** use for mobiles
    else {
        deviceId = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    }
    return deviceId;
```

Answer (score 2):

> Any chances that below method should not return unique value?

AFAIK the UDID is based on the device itself. As far as I know, that means the software is irrelevant (assuming Android OS, but software here = any version of android). Meaning no, you will always get a unique ID for the device. Please note that you will always get the same UDID on the same device.

Comment: But the real time problem i have faced motog4 play (GSM+CDMA). In app we have access UUID of device which id 15 digit number.  and switch off the devices because I have to courier them to the client. When they switch on the device and try to access our app in that different and that is 14 digit number UUID . And and similarity between these two ids is only last digits differ.                                                                                      
eg. Before restart it : 123456789012345 after restart 12345678901234
   its mealtime scenario which observe for 140 mobile devices